# How to append custom data to ebean entity?

Tags: java, database, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

Suppose I have following class

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends Model {

    @Id
    public int id;
    public String email;
    @ManyToOne
    public List<Order> orders;
    public HashMap<String, Object> additionalData;

    public static Finder<String, Customer> find = new Finder<String, Customer>(String.class, Customer.class);

    public static List<Customer> getCustomersWithOpenOrders(){
        return find
                .fetch("orders")
                // with "order.state = 'open'" count > 0
                // add total sum of all orders to 'additionalData' collection
                .findList();
    }
}
```

How to store sum of all orders in `additionalData` collection?

Comment: I don't clearly understand: the `additionnalData` collection must contain the sum for each order ? If yes, it should be `HashMap<Order, Integer> additionalData;` or `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` with the key containing the order id.

Comment: Also, your finder should be of type `Finder<Integer, Customer> find` because you have an integer for the primary key.

Comment: additionalData is a generic store for additional data. I want to store sum as ("sum" -> 42)

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the `Formula` annotation: http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/Formula.html

Comment: @nico_ekito this should be marked as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at the [Formula annotation](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/Formula.html).

But for using this, you have to create a new property in order to store this value, then you can put this value in your map:

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;
    public String email;
    @ManyToOne
    public List<Order> orders;

    @Transient
    @Formula(...) // write the query to compute the sum
    public Integer totalOrders;

    public HashMap<String, Object> additionalData;

    public static Finder<Integer, Customer> find = new Finder<Integer, Customer>(Integer.class, Customer.class);

    public static List<Customer> getCustomersWithOpenOrders(){
        ...// call the finder

        additionalData.put("sum", totalOrders);
        ...
    }
...
}
```